# Diagonally-translated histogram on a torus

Tags: graph-theory

Let $u=(u_1,...,u_n)\in\left\{1,2,...n\right\}^n$ and consider a cylinder $M$ with $n$ rows and $n$ columns.

For each column $j$, we put a $1$ entry at the intersection with the $i$-row and if $u_j>1$ we put consecutive $1$ directly  under the diagonal such that the number of $1$ of the row is $u_j$, ( so we put  $0$ on other coefficient of the column.)

In other words, if we denote by $k[n] $ the smallest positive integer such that $k[n]=k \mod(n)$ ,  $M$ can be vied as a (0,1)-entries-matrix s.t. the coefficient on the $ i$-th row and the $j$-th column is $1$ iff $(i-j)[n]<u_j$

Now if $v_i$ is the number of $1$ on the $i$-th row, we define $f(u)=(v_1,...,v_i)$,

(i.e  $f(u)=M. [1,1,...,1]^t$)

---

For example if  $u=(2,3,3,4,3)$, the cylinder would be

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 0 &1 & 1 & 0 &0\\0& 1&1&1&0\\ 0&0&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

$f(u)=(3,4,2,3,3)$

---

You can compose $f$ with himself and get $f(f(u))=f^2(u)$,

(terminological note : rows from $f^j(u)$ have the same weight than column of $f^{j+1}(u)$, it underlies a  "torus", that's why I mentioned it in the title)

I noticed that if $u_1+u_2+...+u_n=kn$ for some positive integer $k$, then there exist an integer $r$, such that $f^r(u)=(k,...,k)$ (**)

The proof is not hard but pleasant to me, I will give it if anyone asks. The question is regarding another kind of "regulation", without having to compose $f$ with itself :

> Suppose that $u_1+...+u_n=n(n-1)/2$, is it always true that $f(u)$ is the list of the out degrees of the vertex of some tournament?

Note that $t_i\leq  t_2\leq....\leq t_n$ is  the increasing sequence of the out degrees of a tournament (i.e 
a complete directed graph) iff :

for any $k\leq n$ , $t_1+t_2+...+t_k\leq k(k-1)/2$, with equality if $k=n$. (wikipedia says this (easy) result is attribute to Landeau, but I don't know if it is the famous one)
This formula unsure that such a list has a certain smoothness, in a way that the entries of it cannot variate to abruptly... this is why I relate this question to (**)

Note that (**) and the general problem, might have an interest if we adapt it to infinity.

Comment: Thank you David White for the edits, when i look back i feel that i could have avoid half of the gramlatical mistakes by a carefull reading... thank you + sorry